# Iterating through an array of strings in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to SQL. Still learning.
I know that postgres can store array data, but how would I go about performing operations on that data? I have an n-length array of strings supplied by the user. I want to check if each string exists on the table before inserting it.

I've made an attempt, but I don't know if I'm doing this properly. I am connecting to the db using Massive if that helps any

The query is made with array of strings passed in.

```
DECLARE
  a text[] = $1
FOREACH i IN ARRAY a
LOOP 

DO 
$do$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT tag_id FROM test_table WHERE tag_name = i) THEN
    INSERT INTO test_table (tag_name) 
    VALUES ($1);
END IF;
END
$do$

END LOOP;
```

I've got an "error: syntax error at or near'text'", but that may be the least of my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a LOOP, you can `unnest` an array then test to see if the value(s) are in the other table, like so:

```
INSERT INTO test (tag_name)
SELECT tag_name
FROM (SELECT unnest(a) AS tag_name) AS arr -- unnest the array and use like a table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test_table WHERE tag_name = arr.tag_name) -- ensure tag_name is NOT in the test_table
```

This will insert only values from the array that are not already listed in `test_table`.

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely. I'm inputting the following 
    INSERT INTO test_table (tag_name)
    SELECT tag_name FROM (SELECT unnest($1) AS tag_name) AS arr
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT tag_name FROM test_table WHERE tag_name = arr.tag_name)
If I understand (and I don't think I do), this treats the array as a one-column table and then inserts a row into the table if the array item is not found. That's great, but the query fails if there are any duplicates. If none of the items would be duplicates, then there is no error, but they're not inserted either.

Comment: If you are saying you need to insert values that *don't* match, then use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's not too hard. Thank you very much.